# Is it possible to manage Vagrant machines via a custom name?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I usually can do operations over my boxes via:

```
vagrant <command argument> <box id>
```

However, I find this kinda tedious as I actually must remember the ID each machine got.

**Can't I assign a custom name to any machine the way I can manage them by `vagrant <command argument> <custom name>`?**

## Update

I added this to the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.define "customname" do |customname|
end
```

And that brought a machine with such name visible from `vagrant status`, **however** I can't call `vagrant ssh customname` yet ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, and you're on the right track with your update.

The box name which is used in Vagrant commands comes from the config name, as you've updated. You can see more examples under the documentation for [Multi-Machine](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/)

You can also control the name as seen by VirtualBox: [Configuration - VirtualBox Provider](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html)

In your update it looks like you've defined it as "customname" correctly. After creating that VM, you should be able to `vagrant ssh customname`. If that's not working, you may need to destroy and recreate it once (after the name changed).